# How to check report for all feature files runned under regression?

Tags: karate

[image]

So I have 6 different feature files that I run from a regression class that has regression tags. Therefore, scripts with the @regression tag will be executed in all feature files in `classpath:com`.
But my concern that I get 1 report for each function file separately. Is there a way to get all 6 reports of object files in 1 HTML report?

In first screenshot you can see that i have 1 feature file runned, but when I go to cpas feature file scenarios are 39

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are showing is the JUnit runner, and you seem to have missed the existence of the parallel runner that teams are recommended to use for CI: https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution

And what most teams do is add the `cucumber-html-reports` dependency and use that HTML report - which is a single, aggregated one: https://github.com/intuit/karate#test-reports

```
Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "demo");
ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
reportBuilder.generateReports();
```

P.S. read the docs, totally worth it :P

Comment: Your documents are really good, but in some places I find it hard to understand for me. that is why i ask here. I saw reports on cucumber in parallel, but thought that I did not work in parallel, so I did not need this. but now I’ll try to implement this and see the report. thanks

Comment: so i added cucumber report dependency to my project, where i need to add this code ?

Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "demo");
ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
reportBuilder.generateReports();

Comment: how i understood, this goes to my regression runner class as a separate method?

Comment: @SaidYusifli lol. read the docs. and follow the links in the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/DemoTestParallel.java

Comment: Yes i was there also. I couldnt import listFiles inside of fileUtils. Looks like i need to add some more dependencies:)  thank you Peter. Again, i am following all docs:)